# How to move the variable product price field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this function to add a variation and quantity fields to my archive pages-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_select_variations' );

function my_select_variations() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

I am then removing the price range from all pages using this-

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );

function my_remove_variation_price( $price ) {
$price = '';
return $price;
}
```

This works well, however I am not satisfied with the order of the files for my variation products. How can I change the order of the variation price so that it is above the drop down box, as illustrated here? Is there a simple way to do this through the I better off using jQuery to relocate the price?

[image: Illustration]

EDIT: Using the below I have moved the price on single product pages, but not on archive pages yet.

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
```

Comment: You need to change the place of the code in woocommerce template file of your theme. Have you tried this?

Comment: Hi, I have not tried, which template file should I look at editing? Thank you

Comment: Open the woocommerce folder of your template, and try to search in files HTML parts that your page does have, for exampla part with checkout button, or add to card. You can do it with any text editor like VSCode or sublime text. in that file you shold make chages and make replacement